# How to find integral in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, integral

How should I calculate the following integral in Matlab?

[image: click to open image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun = @(x) (2*x -1).^(1/3)
ans = integral(fun,5,13)
```

In case this doesn't work try this

```
fun = @(x) (2*x -1).^(1/3)
quadgk(fun,5,13) 

ans =

   20.3924
```

write the function. calculate integral

Comment: but it not works, says that error: 'integral' undefined near line 1 column 7

Comment: @KamranSoftrock what is your matlab version?

Comment: your last answer worked, thanks a lot. i'm compiling online on octave-online

Comment: @KamranSoftrock If the answer helped you, you should still consider marking it as accepted. And also if you're compiling on octave you should consider tagging your question with `octave` tag.